# How do I add a group I created, and only that group, as a grantee in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

**The goal**

I have a few users I created from IAM > Users. I want these users, and only these users, to access my files in my s3 bucket.

**The problem**

I thought I can add these users to a group. After I created a group in IAM > Groups I expect it to show in list of grantee when I'm changing permissions of a file in my bucket.

Problem is, it doesn't. That means somewhere along the way my understanding might be wrong. But then again in [official AWS S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) there is no information about this (I can hardly believe!).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently AWS doesn't support IAM `group` or `role` as Principal for S3 buckets. I had the same requirement and from this [discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=356160) it is clear there is no support for group ARN or role ARN in bucket policy.

> The format and use of the IAM policies was brought over to s3 for the
>   bucket policies but as you have seen group are not valid within s3
>   bucket policy. I can also let you know that roles are also not
>   available within the s3 bucket policies.